# Which collection for different datatypes and sort mechanism

Tags: excel, vba

I have variables with two values:

```
V11|63|40
V22|12|6
V09|80|20
```

My goal is do perform the following thing:

For each variable substract the second value from the first. Sort the results and return the top two results with there variablenames.

In this case:

```
V09|60
V11|23
```

I started to solve this with arrays but an array can only hold values of the same datatype so the variablenames made some problems. 
I tried dictionary but that can hold only one key and one value (as soon as I understood). Could anyone tell me what is a good collection object to perform what I want to?

Comment: `I tried dictionary but that can hold only one key and one value`. Dictionary value can hold array of values. Are you getting your data in a Range of cell from a worksheet?

Comment: atm i have two worksheets both have a column for the variable name. Worksheet 1 hat the first values worksheet two the second values. So each value is in a cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is suited for one worksheet, but I am sure you can adapt this code for multiple worksheets.

```
Sub substrSort()
    Dim startColumn As Integer, startRow As Integer
    startColumn = 2     'Column with names is B
    startRow = 3        'Row with first variable is 3
    Const numOfEntries As Integer = 3   'count of variables
    Dim varnames(numOfEntries - 1) As String
    Dim results(numOfEntries - 1) As Integer
    Dim resultsSorted(1) As Integer '2 entries
    Dim namesSorted(1) As String    '2 entries
    namesSorted(0) = ""
    namesSorted(1) = ""

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim tmpA As Integer, tmpB As Integer
    For i = 0 To numOfEntries - 1
        varnames(i) = ActiveSheet.Cells(startRow + i, startColumn)
        tmpA = ActiveSheet.Cells(startRow + i, startColumn + 1)
        tmpB = ActiveSheet.Cells(startRow + i, startColumn + 2)
        results(i) = tmpA - tmpB
    Next i

    For i = 0 To numOfEntries - 1
        If results(i) > resultsSorted(0) Then
            resultsSorted(1) = resultsSorted(0)
            resultsSorted(0) = results(i)
            namesSorted(1) = namesSorted(0)
            namesSorted(0) = varnames(i)
        ElseIf results(i) > resultsSorted(1) Then
            resultsSorted(1) = results(i)
            namesSorted(1) = varnames(i)
        End If
    Next i

    ActiveSheet.Cells(startRow, startColumn + 5) = namesSorted(0)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(startRow, startColumn + 6) = resultsSorted(0)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(startRow + 1, startColumn + 5) = namesSorted(1)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(startRow + 1, startColumn + 6) = resultsSorted(1)
End Sub
```

Some explanations:

- startColumn, startRow and numOfEntries set the "range" (not a typical VBA range though)
- I use two arrays (varnames and results) and only work with the results to sort them. Because of this arrangement, indices of the results and their variable names match